# Cannot use typeof on a class property which has two potential types (Biginteger | null)

Tags: typescript

I have a class as follows with a public property which can either be a biginteger or null. I want to be able to detect if it's null using typeof:

```
class Chart {

    public  cx: BigInteger | null;


    public constructor() {


        this.cx = null;


    }

}
```

If I check later on with this:

```
  if ( typeof this.cx == "null") {
                console.log('is null')
            }
```

But this gives the error: `This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"string" | "number" | "bigint" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"' and '"null"' have no overlap.`

How can I check this

Comment: In JavaScript, `typeof null === 'object'` will resolve to `true`, see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#null). You can directly check for `null` :  `if ( this.cx === null) { }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for `null` you can't use `typeof`, just checking with `===` will do:

```
class Chart {
    public cx: BigInteger | null;

    public constructor() {
        this.cx = null;
    }

    public test() {
        if (this.cx === null) {
            console.log(this.cx);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCAWYBOAXaBvAUNH0AOArgEYgCWw0wAHgFzQBCpA5gJIB2KApk50tAD7Q2BECADcmbLkIlylAPZsIKJAWAp5SABQBKDFNy4U8UhAB01aAF4hI8QegBfSYZlkKXZbv2HDpAGbQWsamFlTWVjbConpYvvEKSvIgnGYg8kzBJubUOhIJTg7OjkA).